# list with right positioned flyout does not stay within container

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have a series of post titles that visually form a list. Upon hovering over a row in the list, a `<div>` containing the post content becomes visible at the right edge of the row, behaving like a flyout menu. This flyout `<div>` has a greater height than the row (in most cases). Its height is also variable, so it is not predictable.

[See here](http://templesmc.staging.wpengine.com/tutv/schedule/?date=2012-02-01). Scroll to the bottom.

Because this flyout `<div>` is absolutely positioned to the right of its parent, it achieves the desired flyout effect.

But if you scroll to the bottom of the list, you can see that the last item extends below the bottom edge of `#schedule-section-container`'s border. I would like to correct this in the cleanest way possible.

I know this is because of the positioning. But is there a way that the same flyout effect could be achieved without guesstimating a `margin-bottom`? I would like to use floats, but I don't know how to get the list to keep its short height while having a flyout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just CSS this can be a little tricky, but I think what you're looking for is this:

```
.hentry:last-child > .entry-content { bottom: 0; }
```

That will position the last child to the bottom rather than the top, giving the desired effect without exceeding the bounds of the container. Since the last few actually exceed the bounds a bit, you could also try :nth-last-child to count from the end, like this:

```
.hentry:nth-last-child(1) > .entry-content { bottom: 0; } /* This is last child */
.hentry:nth-last-child(2) > .entry-content { bottom: 0; } /* Second to last */
.hentry:nth-last-child(3) > .entry-content { bottom: 0; } /* Third to last, etc */
```

Might need to add some more specificity to the beginning to limit it to just this page since Wordpress uses .hentry in a few places, but this should give you a good jump off point. Also, if older IE support is required, you might want to consider using [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com)

Comment: Works out great, thanks Andrew. I did need to add the declaration `top: inherit;` to each of those in order to override the original `top: 0;`. Also, the actual selector I'm using is `body.slug-schedule #schedule-section .hentry` so that should work plenty fine. :)